# Kafka security - secure producers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have been reading about kafka security and looks like ACKLs is the way to go to have a secure kafka setup. But my question is :

> 1)Consumer level: Is there a way to have more granular control over
>   what part of the data can be read on our topics. For example: can we
>   somehow make sure some part of our Kafka message, say ssn is not
>   visible for certain users?
>
> 2) Producer level: let's assume we have a topic for voters, and we
>   have different producers writing to that topic with `write` ackls on
>   that topic. How do we control, say a producer from state Missouri says
>   a voter voted in Illinois he has write ackls on the voters topic
>   whereas in reality he should not. Is having a per state topic the only
>   solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Both of your questions are sort of pointing to per-field entitlements/encryption/tokenization. This is not supported by default in core Kafka, but can be implemented at the producers/consumers if you have the knowledge and infrastructure.

For question 1 you'd tokenize/encrypt any fields and only clients with the correct keys could decrypt the payload.

For question 2 you'd encrypt the entire record payload, possibly using Kafka's headers to determine the key pair required to decrypt the data.

In both cases you'll need some key management system to ensure the producers and consumers have access to the keys they require and you'll need to write your own encryption/decryption processes into the clients. I'd implement this in the serializer/deserializer to make it simple.

If you don't want to do all this then separating access to data via ACLs applied to topics is the best approach.